# how to create two table objects by one viewset django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Hi i am trying to save objects in reviews table from posts table filtered by type="R"

i think i should override def create but i don't know how. please help me thanks.

my posts table
[image]

my reviews table
[image]

this is my post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Post."""

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'posts'
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

    POST_TYPE = (
        ('R', 'review'),
        ('C', 'clubpost'),
        ('A', 'advertisement'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=False,
        verbose_name='제목'
    )
    content = models.TextField(
        max_length=2000,
        null=False,
        verbose_name='내용'
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        verbose_name='글쓴이',
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=POST_TYPE,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='글 종류',
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        verbose_name='생성 일시',
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        verbose_name='수정 일시',
    )
```

review model

```
class Review(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'reviews'
        verbose_name = 'Review'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reviews'

    post = models.OneToOneField(
        Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="review",
    )
```

post serializer

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    author = UserAbstractSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'content',
            'author',
            'type',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'title': {
                'error_messages': {
                    'required': '제목을 입력해주세요.',
                }
            },
            'content': {
                'error_messages': {
                    'required': '내용을 입력해주세요.',
                }
            }
        }
```

review serializer

```
class ReviewSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    post_id = PostSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'id',
            'post_id',
        ]
```

review viewset

```
class ReviewViewSet(PostViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(type="R"),
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(author=self.request.user, type="R")
```

i think i should override create method in review viewset but i dont know how to write

wanna figure out how to create two table objects by one viewset django rest framework

Comment: Hi there, it is easy. In your Post model you can overwrite the save() method. Then there you can add some logic like `if field == 'R': ModelName.objects.create(....)`. Understand? Or you can add the same logic withing the create() method from the ModelSerializer(). Therefore, you just need to see where you want to live your business logic.